# Use of internal weights for Weighted Overlay suitability modeling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics

I have derived 'external criterian weights/overall factor weights' applying Pairwise Comparison table. Similarly, pairwise comparison table was used to calculate 'internal weights' separately for each factor.

E.g. for a given suitability modeling, overall factor weight for Landcover resulted as 34% and internal weights were calculated as;

Barren = 41%
Forest = 7%
Low Veg = 39%
Built = 8%
Agriculture land =5%

Now, as listed above internal weights are calculated in percent unit, I am unsure how would I convert them to make compatible with given 1-9 evaluation scale in 'Weighted Overlay' tool enabling me to assign internal weights to each class?

Comment: Since they are already in percent it seems like a 1-10 scale might be easier.  If you want to used 1-9 then just scale your current numbers to that range. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio

Comment: I am not intending to 'stretch' the output by rescaling. The intention is to get relative scores (1-9) based on computed weights in percentage. What might be the relative score given available weights given that Weighted Overlay entertains reclassified grid.